# "Unexpected end of file" error while uncompressing lzma file

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, compression, tar, file-recovery

I've got a file called `foo.tar.lzma`. While trying to decompress it, I get "Unerwartetes Dateiende" ("Unexpected end of file"). I assume I lost quite a lot of bytes, but 1.1 GB are still there.

The file is quite old and all my backups contain the same corrupted file.
Is there any way to recover the data which is in the remaining part of the archive?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, also have Windows XP installed, and I can also visit someone to use a Mac.

Comment: How are you decompressing it? How was it compressed?

Comment: compressed: I assume it was tar -cf foo.tar bar && lzma -9 foo.tar -- decompressing: I've been trying unlzma foo.tar.lzma and tar -cJf foo.tar.lzma

Comment: What's giving the error? `tar` or `unlzma`? And I hope the `-cJf` is a typo, `-Jf` would make more sense.

Comment: $ unlzma -t foo.tar.lzma 
unlzma: foo.tar.lzma: Unerwartetes Eingabe Ende

Comment: tar xJf foo.tar.lzma 
xz: (stdin): Unerwartetes Eingabe Ende
tar: Unerwartetes Dateiende im Archiv.
tar: Unerwartetes Dateiende im Archiv.
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Sorry, my fault. lzma didn't produce new files and tar gave errors. But I didn't see tar xJf extracted at least the remaining data

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault. `lzma` didn't produce new files and tar gave errors. But I didn't see `tar xJf` extracted at least the remaining data